# How would a chat application using HTTP look like?

Tags: http, networking, websocket, chat

So a chat application with Websockets, user A can send any number of messages to the user B and user B can any number of messages to the user A. What if the chat application is built using HTTP protocol, would it work the same way but with more latency?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use the HTTP protocol instead of TCP or UDP it would look a little different. With the HTTP protocol you cannot simply send a packet from user A directly to user B, you would first need something like a RESTful web API to send the requests to. So it would look something like this:

1. user A sends POST request to the web API with the message as the request body
2. the web API receives and stores the message
3. user B sends a GET request to the web API requesting to see the stored message
4. the web API receives the get request and returns the message to user B

this might have a little more latency than using other protocols. You can also add authentication in your API to verify the users before accepting or returning any messages.